# port forwarding on windows server 2008 to Hyper-v machines

Tags: windows-server-2008, port-forwarding

I have a host machine (win server 2008 R2) with several Hyper-V virtual machines. I want to be able to redirect certain ports of host to virtual machines.
There is virtual network connection between host and virtual machines (192.168.10.xxx).
Host is also attached to external network (10.10.10.123).
Virtual machines have several other networks between them.

E.g., I want to be able to redirect traffic from 10.10.10.123 12345 to 192.168.10.321 54321

I tried RRAS in windows server but for it to work Default gateway to 10.10.10.123 has to be set in virtual machines. 
Virtual machines can not be on external network.

Comment: 192.168.10.321 made me giggle.  Good question though.

Comment: :D I just noticed that, I will not remove it... Let it stay as a reminder of what happens when one uses numeric keyboard without thinking...

Answer (score 1):

You need to have router (or server) on public 10.10.10.x subnet, that has also lan interface in subnet 192.168.10.x , so than you need to do NAT and port forwarding.

So which router do you have currently that connects this subnets? cisco ? RRAS ?